# Shouldn't annotating nonexisting dict field produce error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Could someone explain why there is no error when annotating nonexisting field of dict?

```py
dict_1 = {}
dict_1['a']: 'aa' #used colon by mistake instead of assign, code passes without any error on python3.7.2

print(__annotations__) # prints empty dict {}
dict_1['a'] # as expected KeyError: 'a'
```

Edit: After testing more cases I found out that annotating existing dict field also silently produces no result.

```py
dict_2 = {'a': 'b'}
dict_2['a']: 'c' # no error here so I would expect to get new annotation
print(__annotations__) # produces empty dict {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate any valid assignment target.  Reference [Annotating Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#annotating-expressions) from PEP 536:

> The target of the annotation can be any valid single assignment
>   target, at least syntactically (it is up to the type checker what to
>   do with this):
>
> ```
> class Cls:
>     pass
>
> c = Cls()
> c.x: int = 0  # Annotates c.x with int.
> c.y: int      # Annotates c.y with int.
>
> d = {}
> d['a']: int = 0  # Annotates d['a'] with int.
> d['b']: int      # Annotates d['b'] with int.
> ```
>
> Note that even a parenthesized name is considered an expression, not a
>   simple name:
>
> ```
> (x): int      # Annotates x with int, (x) treated as expression by compiler.
> (y): int = 0  # Same situation here.
> ```

The [documentation for annotated assignment statements](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements), would indicate that those values are not stored.  Presumably it's left up to the static type checking tool to store them.

> For expressions as assignment targets, the annotations are evaluated if in class or module scope, but not stored.

Comment: So your answer clears why there is no syntax error for assignments to non existing fields of a dict. Pep 526 also explains in section [other uses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#other-uses-of-annotations) that one can use any string as annotation. My last question is: where are these annotations stored when `__annotations__` returns empty dict? How can I retrieve these annotations? Or are they only interpreted by type checking tools?

Comment: The [documentation for annotated assignment statements](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/simple_stmts.html#annotated-assignment-statements), would indicate that those values are not stored.  Presumably it's left up to the static type checking tool to store them.